# iPhoneX doesn't alert me when receiving text messages from a particular contact

Tags: iphone, notifications, text

My iPhone X won't alert me when I receive a text from one particular contact. This is happening with only one contact. It vibrates, but there is no notification, and when I open the Messages app, the message that was sent to me appears as if it has already been read. I do not have do not disturb on, and have tried to set a special text tone for this one contact.

Comment: Do you have Hide Alerts enabled for that individual contact? See example here: https://www.iphonelife.com/content/how-to-turn-do-not-disturb-individual-contacts-iphone

Comment: I have exactly the same thing on my iPhone 6s after upgrade to iOS 11.3. "Hide alerts" is "off". "Do not disturb" is "off". The phone vibrates only if I hold it in my hand with screen unlocked, otherwise nothing. No badge on the icon. When I open messages app - the message is marked as read. And this does not happen on my MacBook at the same time - I can see notifications on the laptop, but not on the phone, even if the laptop is off. And ONLY from ONE contact. The most important one. My wife.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you said you do not have "Do not disturb" but there is also a contact specific setting "Hide alerts."

Go to Messages> select the contact that for which you don't receive the notification and make sure the "Hide alerts" toggle is not enabled.

Comment: I have exactly the same thing on my iPhone 6s after upgrade to iOS 11.3. "Hide alerts" is "off". "Do not disturb" is "off". The phone vibrates only if I hold it in my hand with screen unlocked, otherwise nothing. No badge on the icon. When I open messages app - the message is marked as read. And this does not happen on my MacBook at the same time - I can see notifications on the laptop, but not on the phone, even if the laptop is off. And ONLY from ONE contact. The most important one. My wife.

Answer (score -1):

Wife had the same problem. Couldn’t find any solution.

Then we went with a good old fashioned power cycle. And.....problem solved.